# Nodejs-MongoDB How can i get data by _id and title

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to get my data with 2 function.

1. for get by collectionid.
2. function for getbytitle.

How can I make it ? In normally i getting my datas like :

```
router.get("/:collectionId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Article.findOne({ collectionid: req.params.collectionId}).populate('author').then(x=>{
      res.json(x)
    })
    
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

But with that function i can only get with collectionid. How can i make for both ?

Thanks for replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can have serverale in find like that:

.findOne({ collectionid: req.params.collectionId, title: titleyouwant })

See here: [Mongoose - multiple parameters in findOne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854448/mongoose-multiple-parameters-in-findone)

Comment: Thanks for reply brother! But when i want find collectionid or _id from mongodb. Like  `router.get("/:collectionId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Article.find({ collectionid: req.params.collectionId,_id:req.params.collectionId}).populate('author').then(x=>{
      res.json(x)
    })
    
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});`
Its always giving me empty array.

Comment: For example when i write id (_id or collectionid ) to my get request it will find it and show me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake your are doing in this. Don't use async/await and then/catch together. You can do something like this:

```
router.get("/:collectionId", async (req, res) => {
  try {
        const post = await Article.findOne({ collectionid: req.params.collectionId}).populate('author');
        console.log(post)
   
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

If you need a query for `getbytitle`  in the same route, I cam add it.